# Javascript decodes encoded string automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've been reading a blog post and I saw something which says JS Encoding Vulnerability. In the sample code below, if the user enters something like this :

`\x3cscript\x3e%20alert(\x27pwnd\x27)%20\x3c/script\x3e`, it says JS will render it as HTML which looks odd to me. I tried it and he was right.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2 id="welcome-message">Welcome to our website</h2>

@if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.UserName)) {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //ViewBag.Username value comes from Controller.
        var message = 'Welcome, @ViewBag.UserName!';
        $("#welcome-message").html(message).hide().show('slow');
    });
</script>
}
```

My question is, why Javascript decodes already encoded string automatically? Or it does have something with jQuery's `html()` function which does that? The OP says use `Ajax.EncodeJavascriptString()` method in order to solve this problem. But why will I need to encode already encoded string? I checked jQuery's website and it doesn't mention anything like that for [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method.

If you like to see the whole blog post, please visit this address http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/04/28/preventing-javascript-encoding-xss-attacks-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Perhaps I miss the ASP.NET bits (I'm not a .NET programmer) but I don't understand why you should use `.html()` to inject plain text.

Comment: Imagine we are injecting some markup along with the  username.

Comment: a) how do you get that string? b) how will the output look (I'm no ASP programmer), does it just replace `@ViewBag.UserName` with the *plain*, *unescaped* string?

Comment: @Bergi Could you please check the URL I gave in the question. It explains where that comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the HTML result:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var message = 'Welcome, \x3cscript\x3e alert(\x27pwnd\x27) \x3c/script\x3e!';
        $("#welcome-message").html(message).hide().show('slow');
    });
</script>
```

Yet, that JS string contains some [character escape sequences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Unicode_escape_sequences) and is equal to

```
'Welcome, <script> alert("pwnd") </script>!'
```

So, we want to escape these escape sequences (including simple things like `\n` or `\t`) as well as the JS string delimiters `'` and `"` - by using `@Encoder.JavaScriptEncode`.

Comment: I will review the link you gave. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Just to add to this answer: the reason this happens is that the @ syntax in .cshtml / .vbhtml files is not context-aware.  It performs *only* HTML-encoding.  For all other encoding types (such as Javascript or CSS), the page author must make an explicit call to the correct encoding routine, as in Bergi's solution.